# Как вычислить и вывести отличающийся элемент из списка?

Tags: python, list

Есть два массива `a` и `b`, в них хранятся условные имена. Если какое-либо имя(или больше одного имени) в массиве `a` отличается от имени в массиве `b`, то оно должно выводится на экран, если нет то ничего не происходит. Как это сделать?

```
a = [str(input())]
b = [str(input())]
if a == b:
    print("ok")
else:
```

Comment: можно пожалуйста пример входных и выходных данных?

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [str(input())]
```

так список имен не передают (кстати зачем ввод превращать в текст через `str`, если он и так является строкой?), вот так тогда уж, если вы имена через пробел делаете

```
a = input().split()
```

а ваша задача может решаться так:

```
res = [name for name in a if name not in b]

print(res, sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я все правильно понял, если у тебя массивы одинаковой длины, можно так:

```
    a = [str(input())]
    b = [str(input())]
    if a == b:
        print("ok")
    else:
        for i in range(len(a)):
            if a[i] !== b[i]:
                print(a[i])
```

Если нет, нужно добавить проверку, что i не превышает длину массива b:

```
    a = [str(input())]
    b = [str(input())]
    if a == b:
        print("ok")
    else:
        for i in range(len(a)):
            if i < len(b):
                if a[i] !== b[i]:
                    print(a[i])
```

Иначе, обращение к несуществующему элементу, приведет к ошибке list index out of range.

Comment: а что вы хотите сделать через `a = [str(input())]` - создать массив из 1 строки? ну так у вас тогда и `a` и `b` будут всегда одного размера - размером 1 :)

Comment: Только сейчас заметил, что человек похоже написал что-то не то, input.split() там должно быть конечно)))